# Python Image Background

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a quiz using replit python and my background image code doesn't work.
The following code is what I'm using for my initial class but I'd also like to apply the working background image code to my other classes that come after it.

I get an indentation error either in the 'background_color = "SteelBlue"' or the 'self.app_frame=Frame(parent, bg = background_color, padx=200, pady=300)' sections of code depending on my attempts to fix them.

```
class Menu:
    def __init__(self, parent):
    background_color = "SteelBlue"
    self.app_frame=Frame(parent, bg = background_color, padx=200, pady=200)
    self.menu_image = Image.open("image1.png")
    self.menu_image = self.menu_image.resize((300, 200), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
    self.menu_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.menu_image)
   
    self.app_frame=Frame(parent, bg = background_color)
    self.app_frame.grid()        
    self.image_label= Label(self.app_frame, image=self.menu_image)
    self.image_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        self.heading_label=Label(self.app_frame, text="dum quiz", font=("Helvetica","18","bold"),bg=background_color)
        self.heading_label.grid(row=0, padx=20)

        self.var1=IntVar()

        self.heading_label=Label(self.app_frame, text="Insert username below: ", font=("Helvetica","16"),bg=background_color)
        self.heading_label.grid(row=1, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.entry_box=Entry(self.app_frame)
        self.entry_box.grid(row=2, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.continue_button=Button(self.app_frame, text="Continue", font=("Helvetica", "13", "bold"), bg="LightBlue", command=self.name_collection)
        self.continue_button.grid(row=3, padx=20, pady=20)

    def name_collection(self):
        name=self.entry_box.get()
        names.append(name)
        self.app_frame.destroy()
        Quiz(root)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Move `background` to `self.image_label` to indentaion 4 spaces same as you did `self.heading_label`

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
      from PIL import ImageTk, Image # library 

      self.menu_image  = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("image1.png").resize((300, 100), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS))
      self.image_label= Label(self.app_frame, image=self.menu_image)
```